# draw line/point on existing UIView without drawRect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, layer, drawrect

I created line chart. Now I need to display point on this chart when I tap the screen.
What would be the best method? Do I need to call `drawRect` method again, draw whole chart with marked point?

I'm thinking about something like transparent layer over the chart `UIView`. 
Can I create another transparent `UIView` and put it on the position of my chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all drawing is done in a view's `drawRect:` you can only optimize your chart's drawing so it can be made to update only a part of it and use `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` (passing the area where the marker should be).

Or you create another UIView subclass that is layered atop of your chart and that does nothing but drawing the markers on a transparent background. Probably easier and faster to implement. It also would have another benefit:

If you make that view only as big as the bounding box of the marker you could also easily animate it, like fading it in and out. Or letting it rotate a little (to see the effect I have in mind, select the "Help" menu in Mac OS X, type something in the search field like "a", and see the marker next to a menu item move a little around a spot).

Comment: I decided to create new UIView on the top of previous.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a portion of your view using `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`.

Comment: In that case, you also need to use the rect parameter in drawRect: to only draw in that rect...

Comment: hm... but will will reauire to calculate what is chart shape in this rect, and after touchesEnded I need to clear this area.  Is it good idea to create another UIView in the same rect?